# Twilio unable to play mp3 file

Tags: twilio

I have the following simple twiml bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Play>https://jade-bat-5280.twil.io/assets/zero-tone.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

The mp3 plays fine if you load it in the browser, but when the TwiML bin is played, when the voice number is called, there is no sound.

Answer (score 1):

That is a DTMF tone.

It depends on the device you are calling from if you hear that tone (say if you use a  for that URL and then associate that TwiML to your Twilio Number).

DTMF is handled as RFC 2833 by carriers. The DTMF tone regeneration for a non-IP end-point should happen on the edge. IP devices should use RFC 2833/4733 to obtain the DTMF.

I don't hear the tone (or hear a small click which is the remnants of the removed DTMF) from my VoIP phone since the DTMF is handled as RTP events. If I call from my cell, I hear the full DTMF tone.

So, it is working as expected.

Comment: I used this on an old apartment to automate letting someone in, allowing this to 'long-press zero' for me since sending a digit only sends it for a short bit (which didn't work previously).

I'm not sure why it worked and I could hear it on the old phone system there but not here, so I'm trying to figure that out.